# Saving properties on the fly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm working on Profile for users on my ASP.NET MVC website. And I have many properties (checkboxes, dropdowns, etc) like:

- Time zone
- DST
- Email settings

I can make my own model to handle all of them like this:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public TimeZoneOptions TimeZone { get; set; }
    public DstOptions Dst { get; set; } // Daylight Saving Time
    public bool EmailSettings1 { get; set; }
    public bool EmailSettings2 { get; set; }
    // ...
    public bool EmailSettings22 { get; set; }
}
```

My view model properties are not tied one to another. So, I don't need to call `ModelState.IsValid`. It seems like my model will always be valid.

If I follow the standard way of saving the model in ASP.NET MVC, it will force my customer to click twice:

1. Change the property
2. Click Save button

But I want them to do that with only one click. Like on this screenshot:

[image]

**I want each property to be marked with "Changes saved" when the user clicks on them**. And *I want to achieve this with a minimum amount of code*. It seems like it's easy to do with:

- jQuery only

or

- Knockout.js

But I can't decide what is better. In jQuery I can manipulate with DOM in direct way. But it seems with knockout it could be more elegant, and I can make my code more maintainable.

I don't know how to do this with knockout, may be some kind of binding needed to update an element when it's saved like this:

```
<span data-bind="display-when-saved-for-property: EmailSettings1"></span>
```

???

Maybe there are other ways to do that. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just have an onchange event for your checkboxes which has an ajax call to your controller. Your controller will save the data and the ajax success callback will display the changes saved message. This is how I would do it. Let me know if you want more details

Comment: @heymega, thanks. And how to detect which property has been changed? I have to submit the entire model to controller, right? So it's the unique ajax url to save the model for all the properties. How can I display "Changes saved" for particular property?

Comment: Give me 10 mins, I'm writing some code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand is that you have list of user configuration that 'll be rendered as `checkbox` or `dropdownlist`.
If so then you are right that KnockoutJS is more elegent way(I had the same problem before except i have a save button, *i'm lucky*). Let's see what we have here:
You have model with mostly `bool` properties, then with no doubt you should use [KnockoutJS mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). Why? all we gonna do simply is to:

1. Write the `view` HTML markup normally.
2. For the first load of our `view`, make an AJAX request to get user profile configuration and then using `mapping plugin` convert the returned data into `ViewModel` and bind it to our `view`(all this without need to write the ViewModel by ourself which mean if the ViewModel on server changed we just need to modify only the `view`).
3. For each `checkbox` or `dropdownlist` add `change` event handler (using jQuery).
4. The `change` function simply convert our binded `ViewModel` into JSON string again using `mapping plugin` (just one line of code)
5. Finally made another AJAX request to save changes.

To show the 'Changes Saved' message you can simply pass refrence of the calling input and using little bit of jQuery magic append your message.

***Update:***
Your could should be look like this (*or maybe better than mine*):

```
var UserProfile;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ViewContainer input:checkbox').change(function (event) {
        SaveUserProfile(event);
    });
    IntializeUserProfile();
});

function IntializeUserProfile() {
    // Show spinner
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL_To_Get_User_Profile,
        data: UserId, // in case of you need to pass data.
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            UserProfile = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data); //ko.mapping.fromJS($.parseJSON(msg));
            ko.applyBindings(UserProfile, selector);
            // Hide Spinner
        }
    });
}

function SaveUserProfile(event) {
    // Show Spinner
    var model = ko.toJSON(ko.mapping.toJS(UserProfile));
    event = event || window.event;
    target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL_To_Save_UserProfile,
        data: model,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // Hide Spinner

            // here you have the caller input ==>target.
            // for example, you can get it's parent to append your message
            // or just show message in the page as notification.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly how I think it should work. But! If I use mapping plugin, how can I pass a reference of the calling input? Is there any way to do this automatically? And how can I display "Changes saved" only in case of success?

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be implemented with knockout + jQuery. With knockout is very easy to build app with changing layout (as in your case). JQuery in your case, is required for async requests.

So, viewmodel:

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    var _isCurrentSavingProp = null;

    self.EmailSettings1 = ko.observable(data.EmailSettings1);
    self.IsEmailSettings1Saved = ko.observable();
    ... another props

    self.EmailSettings1.subscribe(function(val) {            
        isCurrentSavingProp = self.IsEmailSettings1Saved;
        self.save();
    });
    ... another subscribers

    self.save = function() {
        isCurrentSavingProp(false);
        $.post(url, ko.toJSON(self), function() {
            isCurrentSavingProp(true);
        })
    }  
}
```

Html:

```
<span data-bind="visible: IsEmailSettings1Saved" style="display: none"></span>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: EmailSettings1" />
... etc..
```

Comment: +1, but in this case we have to write minimum 5 lines of code for each property. It's okay if I have few of them. But what if I have lots of them? What if I have a lot of forms, and not only this one? My code very soon will become unmaintainable. So I can't accept this as solution, sorry.

I think it could be done via some kind of binding, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: I suggested a solution for your current implementation. If you asked how improve your solution, i would suggest, don't create a bool field for each setting, but store them in array. In this case, server and client code size will be minimized.

Comment: Oh no, I'm not talking about the bytes transferred between client and the server. It's about maintainability. If I have a lot of properties, I have to write "isCurrentSavingProp = self.IsEmailSettings1Saved" for each of them manually. It's quite ineffective, and must be optimized.

Comment: And i'm not about data transfering, too. I suggest you optimize size OF YOUR CODE - use array instead single fields. With array you can easy to set data in view (iterate array), init knockout view model, and save modified data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok your model needs to be something like this.

```
public class MyModel
{

    public bool? Friends { get; set; }
    public bool? Photos { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }

}
```

Your controller method takes in an instance of your model. As long as your ajax request has a data name which matches the name of a property in your model it will bind.

```
    public void UpdateValues(MyModel model)
    {

        if(model.Friends != null)
        {
            //Save
        }
        if (model.Photos != null)
        { 
            //Save
        }
        if (model.Car != null)
        { 
            //Save
        }


    }
```

Lets say your html markup is like this

```
<div id="checkbox-container">
    <div>    
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="friends" />
        My Friends</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="photos" />My Photos</label>
    </div>
    <select id="car-dropdown">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery....

```
$('#checkbox-container input:checkbox').change(function () {
    //Gets the property name we will bind
    var field = $(this).attr("name");
    var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");

    var data = {};
    data[field] = isChecked;

    requestBuilder(data);

 });

//New method for our dropdown
$('#car-dropdown').change(function()
{


    var data = {};
    data['Car'] = $(this).val();

    requestBuilder(data);


});


function requestBuilder(data)
{

    //Ajax Request
    $.ajax({
    //Change url to match your controller
    url:"/Controller/UpdateValues/",
    data:data,
    type:"POST",
    success:function(response)
    {
       alert("Change Saved")
    }
    });

 }
```

Notice how we are passing the Name="" attribute over. This matches the name we have in our model so it will bind :)

Let me know if you need me to expand on any element . I've also created a jsfiddle for the front end code - http://jsfiddle.net/8tKBx/

Good luck!

Comment: Okay, thanks! And now I want "Changes Saved" to be displayed near the clicked property. For instance, if I click My Friends, I want "Changes saved" to be displayed right after this element. But only in case of success. And what if I have dropdown list? I think we can't send the only one property, it would be easier to send the entire model itself to the server.

Comment: Theres a few different ways to do it. Here is a quite change that ive put in but you can experiment and make it your own. http://jsfiddle.net/8tKBx/4/ . I'll edit my original answer to incorporate a dropdown. gimme 5 mins